# Running Django in Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, syntax

Hi I followed a tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Python/article.html#firstpython_program) to install Python in Eclipse and have used the source code provided to run a test

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def addFixedValue(a):
    y = 5
    return y +a

print add(1,2)
print addFixedValue(1)
```

However when I run as Django I get the following error

File "C:\Users\Chris\Python\Python URL test\src\manage.py", line 13

```
print add(1,2)
        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Anybody know what's up?

Comment: You are using Python 3.x.  `print` is no longer a statement but a function.  You should be doing: `print(add(1,2))`.

Comment: Ah thank you! Don't suppose you know of a good list taht summarises the changes?

Comment: You mean the changes to Python that came with version 3?  Sure, they are all listed here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/